# kernel does not support Block I/O weight error, Docker

Tags: docker, resource-limiting

I need to set block IO limit to a docker container.

I decided to try out this docker feature, but I am getting the following:

```
(base) me@ubuntu:~/dev/ws3$ docker run -it --name cont_B --blkio-weight 300 busybox
WARNING: Your kernel does not support Block I/O weight or the cgroup is not mounted. Weight discarded.
/ # exit
```

what does this mean? it is a warning, but it says that it is not going to do what I want? how can I remediate this?

Comment: Clear what it says. *Your kernel does not support Block I/O weight

Comment: @David but kernel is built with CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP_IOCOST, so it should. Probably it requires CFQ I/O scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

This question comes up in search, so I'll add an answer. On github there is a [script that checks for kernel features](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moby/moby/master/contrib/check-config.sh) and tells you which features are missing.